# What is the Difference between Processor register and instruction register?

Tags: arm, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

what is the difference between [Processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) and [Instruction register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_register) in CPU ? what each one used for ?
is Instruction register part of processor registers ?

Comment: What *exactly* confuses you about those two registers? Why shouldn't there be a difference? What makes you think there is none?

Comment: No problem. Regarding your question, do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_register) by "instruction register"? It would be nice if you provided hyperlinks to the terms you are using in your particular question to make sure everybody knows what you are talking about.

Comment: yup , exactly that one , Indeed this is my first day in this topic , so I thought that those terms are well recognized  .

Comment: According to that wikipedia page, *processor register* (or just *register*) is the general term. The instruction register is one of the (processor) registers.

Comment: Well, processor register is kind of obvious, so everybody is going to understand it. I wasn't sure whether you literally meant the instruction register or the program counter (or instruction pointer on x86), though. Others might get it immediately, but you can save the trouble simply by linking to what you mean.

Comment: Now to your actual question: the processor registers are a *group* of registers while the instruction register is one concrete register. You cannot compare a group to a single object, so I don't really understand your question. If you meant to ask if the instruction register is *part of* the processor registers, then write so, please. We can't read people's minds. Otherwise, clarify. Also, pay attention to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181832/what-is-the-difference-between-processor-register-and-instruction-register?noredirect=1#comment71526690_42181832) comment of mine.

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: FYI, I didn't downvote. I honestly understand the reason, though: you're being very vague. You seem to have a lot of questions, which is actually pretty good, but it doesn't fit into the format of Q&A used here on Stack Overflow. This website works with specific questions and expert answers, where the latter needs the former: we cannot give an expert answer to broad or vague questions; that would require writing an entire book. You need to formulate every question you have independently and be very specific. I recommend to read this [How To Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yes, all kinds of CPUs need to be able to have a way to interpret instructions that they have fetched and that fetched instruction needs to be stored in the CPU in some way for the duration (of decoding and executing).  Processor registers or at least general purpose registers are not required, although are quite common.  Stack based processors dont necessarily have general purpose registers but the wiki link covers a wide spread, and even with a stack machine, just like the fetched instruction you need temporary storage for data being processed, and this would fall into that wiki page.

Comment: The reality is there is lots of temporary storage within a processor that is needed by the design.  Each design varies, just like each program written by a programmer varies, even if solving the same task.  There is no real need to use names like these for that storage, been working on processors for years and we never use terms like that, no reason to.  Would be like coming up with a high level name for categories of variables used in a program and talking abou those, rather than just talking about a specific variable on a line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is frowned upon to use links like that in your question.  In this case the links provide adequate/good descriptions.

If you are studying the ARM processor (which is now plural) then you already understand processor registers. Another name for them is general purpose registers.  They are at this high level of thinking very similar to variables in a program, they are right there in your function readily available to use.  In ARM these would be r0,r1,r2,r3, etc.

The instruction register is more of a concept, there may have been a time and you could certainly design something this way, but now we have pipelines so there isnt just one place where an instruction lives.  but barring that.  How must a cpu work?  It has to fetch an instruction from memory, flash or ram or lets leave it at those.  Then the logic has to inspect those bits and determine what instruction it is, and then from there what to do with it.

I sure hope you are starting with the ARM Architectural Reference Manual for the ARMv5 or the oldest one you can find basically and then work forward from there.  That old one is the better one for getting started and not overly complicated with all the protection and other features that come later it covers the nuts and bolts.

so lets take the thumb instruction add.

```
add r1,r2,r3
```

I assemble that and then disassemble I get

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   18d1        adds    r1, r2, r3
```

And looking at the ARM ARM that is exactly what I expected the top 7 bits being 0b0001100 then three groups of three bits describing the three registers, two input operands one the destionation, not necessarily in that order.

So how could a processor do anything useful with this?  First it has to get the instruction from memory so it does some kind of read (a fetch is just a read) from memory to get those bits 0x18D1.  Then it needs to decode those bits.  Well while it is decoding those bits it needs to store those bits for more than the duration of a clock cycle.  That generally means it gets latched into a register.  Well the general purpose registers are not where this goes, somewhere inside the processor we need to store this instruction.  And if you want to call that an instruction register, so be it.  While stored in the processor temporarily we can then decode those bits, some logic will recoginize the top 7 bits and say "hey everybody this is a three register add", and now the processor has to go to get those two input registers.  General purpose or using your wikipedia terms, processor registers.  Those might also get latched into other registers that feed the alu or feed an adder circuit or perhaps the addition happens without the need for that, depends on the design.  The addition happens, and now the result needs to go to the destination register, another processor register.  Along with the flags that go to yet another register, processor state register (generically) or PSR or in ARM terms CPSR.

Now with pipelines though it is more complicated, a pipeline is nothing more than an assembly line you have seen on documentaries, or perhaps have first hand knowledge.  The pipeline is using your wikipedia page a line of instruction registers.  or an array using programming terms.  The instruction is fetched and hits the first stage in the pipe, and like an assembly line different tasks happen at each stage, at some point we decode the instruction, at some point the operands are requested and show up, at some point the addition happens, and the output has to go somewhere along with the flags.  All the while as this addition moves through the pipe ideally right behind it is another addition.  Just like a red car in the assembly line followed by a white and a green each hitting the same step in the process, put the wheels on put the doors on, etc.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph: I advised the OP to add links, so if that's wrong somehow, it's my fault. I don't see why it would be, though. Anyway, in the first sentence you say it's bad, in the second one you say it's good. I don't really know what you mean here.

Comment: I did see you ask that.  The problem with external links is they change or go away, so they are not on the SO server and if they are relevant to the question or answer, then the whole thread loses its value.  I understand the difficulty of trying to understand this question without the links and at the same time you are absolutely correct this too vague and may very well get closed.  And we couldnt have understood the question without the links, but the links do an adequate job of describing those terms so despite my answer, I still dont know the question.

Comment: thank you guys , indeed I learned a lot from this amazing conversation :) 
@old_timer HOW AMAZING U R ! really your answer helps me a lot

Comment: And without plagiarising  the wikipdia articles wholesale and then add to that, where in the arm processor is this type of register, and the another for where is that type of register, I wouldnt know how to ask this question correctly.  Although can understand the desire for this knowledge.  And is it an SO question or an electrical engineering exchange question, once properly asked?  Not sure.

Comment: There is nothing complicated about digital logic. AND, OR, NOT and being able to count from zero to one is it, that is everything you need to know.  Just think through what a processor would need to do.  Write your own instruction set simulator or disassembler, and you will see the light.

Comment: Also note that when you read the ARM ARM, there are "banked registers", there is more than one R13 for example.  How is it possible?  Pretty simple, there are more than one "processor registers" that hold the value for r13, depending on the mode when an instruction needs to access r13 it goes to the mode specific one.